Issue with Apple Sign In using Firebase in Unity
I'm currently working on implementing Apple Sign In in my Unity project using Firebase, but I'm running into some issues. When I tap the sign-in button, the Apple Sign In popup appears, and it seems like the sign-in process completes successfully. However, the authentication results are not reflecting in my game, and I'm unable to proceed.
Here’s the relevant part of my Sign In Manager script:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Auth;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
#if UNITY_IOS
using AppleAuth;
using AppleAuth.Enums;
using AppleAuth.Interfaces;
using AppleAuth.Native;
#endif

public class AppleSigninManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject kidsDetailPanel;
    [SerializeField] GameObject RegisterPanel;
    [SerializeField] DataLoadingScript loadData;

    public TextMeshProUGUI infoText;

    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private string rawNonce; // Declare rawNonce

    private void Awake()
    {
        CheckFirebaseDependencies();
    }

    private void CheckFirebaseDependencies()
    {
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                if (task.Result == DependencyStatus.Available)
                    auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
                else
                    AddToInformation("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + task.Result.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                AddToInformation("Dependency check was not completed. Error : " + task.Exception.Message);
            }
        });
    }

    public void SignInWithApple()
    {
        Debug.Log("Sign In With Apple");
#if UNITY_IOS
        // Generate a rawNonce
        rawNonce = GenerateNonce();
        var appleAuthManager = new AppleAuthManager(new PayloadDeserializer());
        appleAuthManager.LoginWithAppleId(
            LoginOptions.IncludeEmail | LoginOptions.IncludeFullName,
            credential =>
            {
                if (credential is IAppleIDCredential appleIdCredential)
                {
                    var identityToken = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(appleIdCredential.IdentityToken);
                    Debug.LogError("Got Id token: " + identityToken);
                    SignInWithAppleOnFirebase(identityToken);
                }
            },
            error =>
            {
                AddToInformation("Apple Sign-In Failed: " + error.ToString());
            });
#else
        AddToInformation("Apple Sign-In is only supported on iOS.");
#endif
    }

    private void SignInWithAppleOnFirebase(string appleIdToken)
    {
        Firebase.Auth.Credential credential =
            Firebase.Auth.OAuthProvider.GetCredential("apple.com", appleIdToken, rawNonce, null);
        auth.SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }

            Firebase.Auth.AuthResult result = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                result.User.DisplayName, result.User.UserId);

            FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result.User;
            DataSaver.instance.SaveUserId(newUser.UserId);
            loadData.LoadData(newUser.UserId);

            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);

            DataSaver.instance.dts.parentName = newUser.DisplayName;
            DataSaver.instance.dts.mobileNumber = newUser.PhoneNumber;
            DataSaver.instance.dts.email = newUser.Email;
        });
    }

    private string GenerateNonce()
    {
        var nonce = new byte[32];
        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(nonce);
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(nonce);
    }

    IEnumerator Checking(string userId)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("login_ids", userId);
        yield return StartCoroutine(DataSaver.instance.LoadDataEnum());
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DataSaver.instance.dts.childName))
        {
            DataSaver.instance.SaveUserId(userId);
            CompleteProfile();
            print("no data found");
        }
        else
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("UserProfile");
        }
    }

    void CompleteProfile()
    {
        kidsDetailPanel.SetActive(true);
        RegisterPanel.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void AddToInformation(string str) { infoText.text += "\n" + str; }
}


Steps I’ve Taken:
Set up Firebase Authentication in the Firebase Console.
Configured Apple Sign In in the Firebase Console.
Added the necessary permissions and entitlements for Apple Sign In in Xcode.
Called the sign-in function in Unity and checked for success.
Actual Behavior:
The sign-in popup appears and seems to complete, but there are no updates or changes in the game. I’m not getting any errors in the xcode console.
Additional Information:
Unity Version: 2023.2
Firebase SDK Version: 11.9.0
Platform: iOS
If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has suggestions on how to troubleshoot this, I would really appreciate your help!
Thank you!
After a successful sign-in, I expect the user's details to be reflected in my game, and the user should be navigated to their profile page.
Here am adding the XCode log when trying to submit the authentication:
Using Auth Prod for testing
Unloading 219 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded 
Objects now: 5262.
Total: 26.103375 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.207583 ms 
CreateObjectMapping: 0.088125 ms MarkObjects: 2.566959 ms  
DeleteObjects: 23.240708 ms)

Using Auth Prod for testing.
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, 
String, Object)
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()

Using Sign in with Apple Unity Plugin - v1.4.3
-> applicationWillResignActive()
9.6.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800014] Cannot get flag for 
unregistered flag. SDK name, flag name: app_measurement, 
session_stitching_token_feature_enabled
9.6.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800014] Cannot get flag for 
unregistered flag. SDK name, flag name: app_measurement, 
session_stitching_token_feature_enabled
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()


Did you setup the redirect urls in Firebase console and apple account? If I remember correctly, apple login in Firebase is web-based and involves your server, otherwise the result could look like what you describe

"the authentication results are not reflecting in my game, and I'm unable to proceed."
Explain what this means in terms of program state. Also post  all relevant logs (informational, warning and errors all included)

actually what I mean that the function SignInWithAppleOnFirebase which is need to work after sign in with apple is not calling.

Please post your logs

@JoeSpiro Sorry for the delayed response. I’ve attached the logs as requested.

Thank you, @Vladimir . It seems there may be some issues with the redirection, as you mentioned. I’ll check and configure the URLs in the Firebase console and Apple account to resolve this.

It might be that you're using ContinueWith, instead of ContinueWithOnMainThread.  Firebase on Unity must be called on the main thread to be safe.  Can also 'await' in the method.  See this video for reference. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GzFDXvZxKM

Good call @syp5w2qxe; OP please check out Add Firebase to your Unity project for an example
